# How does one export a Room table to a CSV format?

Tags: android, csv, android-room

I have an app right now that stores data in a Room database using several entities. What I need is to take the contents of a table, convert the data into a CSV format, and then to send that format via email. I have the very last part buttoned down, as it simply involves sending the file through an intent with `ACTION_SEND`. That's easy.

I understand that I can get the path to the actual database and manipulate that file. However, the designers of Room went to such great lengths to put SQLite into a black box that this seems like a bad idea.

I know that I can also write a query method in one of the DAOs that returns a string in CSV format that can then be turned into a File object. However, that is a lot of work, and I'm not going to waste my time if someone else has done so for me.

So, here's my question: How do I export a Room database table into a CSV formatted string? If there are multiple ways of doing so, is there a preferred way?

Bonus question: Is there any preferred way to back up the entire database?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exporting Room Database to csv file in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51055184/exporting-room-database-to-csv-file-in-android)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I understand that I can get the path to the actual database and manipulate that file. However, Google has gone to such lengths to obscure the SQLite details that this seems like a bad idea.

Google offers [`getOpenHelper()` on your `RoomDatabase`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase.html#getOpenHelper()), if you have a reason to want to work with the database more directly (e.g., execute arbitrary SQL that is not in your DAO).

> I know that I can also write a query method in one of the DAOs that returns a string in CSV format that can then be turned into a File object

IMHO, creating a CSV file is not the responsibility of a DAO, any more than populating widgets is the responsibility of a DAO.

> How do I export a Room database table into a CSV formatted string?

Create some sort of `Report` class that can query the DAO, generate the CSV, and write it to your desired location.

Or, find some existing code that can take a `Cursor` and generate a CSV from it. Use `getOpenHelper()` to get a `SupportSQLiteDatabase`, on which you can `query()` with your desired SQL to generate the `Cursor`.

> Is there any preferred way to back up the entire database?

IMHO, `close()` the `RoomDatabase`, then copy the files ([using `getDatabasePath()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)) and Java file I/O).

Comment: As to your last statement: how would I go about importing the file I obtain?

Comment: @Patrick: Reverse the process: copy the file from wherever your backup resides back to the location indicated by `getDatabasePath()`.

Answer (score 3):

It's really easy following these steps:

1. On Android Studio go to **View - Tools - Device Files Explorer**
2. Navigate to **/data/data/<your.package>/databases/<your_app_name>** and export the file.
3. Download http://sqlitebrowser.org
4. Open de DB on SQLite Browser, click Browse Data, select the table.
5. Go to **File - Export - Export table(s) as CSV file...**

Source: https://medium.com/@mattyskala/browse-sqlite-database-in-android-studio-4fbba6cca105

Answer (score 2):

It's really easy to export Room DB table to CSV file in **Kotlin** using [kotlin-csv](https://github.com/doyaaaaaken/kotlin-csv) library.

Just get the list of DB table objects:

```
@Dao
interface DirectorDao {
    @get:Query("SELECT * FROM director ORDER BY full_name ASC")
    val allDirectors: LiveData<List<Director>>
}
```

Then user CSV writer to write into the file by going through all list items and adding the column values to CSV rows, one by one, like this:

```
csvWriter().open(csvFile) {
    // Header
    writeRow(listOf("[id]", "[name]", "[age]"))

    directorDao.allDirectors.value.forEachIndexed { index, director ->
        writeRow(listOf(index, director.fullName, director.age))
    }
}
```

I explain the whole flow [here](https://medium.com/@tonia.tkachuk/how-to-export-room-database-to-csv-file-a51fec589618).