# Exporting Room Database to csv file in android

Tags: android, csv, kotlin, export-to-csv, android-room

There are many tutorials available for exporting SQLite database to csv file but not enough stuff for exporting from room database.

Using sqlite export reference [Exporting SQLite Database to csv file in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367270/exporting-sqlite-database-to-csv-file-in-android) parsing each column of row manually for room. Following is my code:

```
     @Dao
     interface CategoryDao {
         @Query("SELECT * FROM Category")
         fun getAllCategory(): List<Category>
     }

//   Export csv logic

      val categoryList = categoryDao.getAllCategory()
      val csvWrite = CSVWriter(FileWriter(file))

      for (item in categoryList) {
         val arrStr = arrayOf<String>(item.categoryId, item.categoryName)
         csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr)
      }
```

Is there any other way to export csv. Even in room not getting  columns name of table pragmatically so not able to create dynamically common logic for all table.

Comment: room database is sqlite database - there is no difference

Comment: You could use Jackson CSV library to map Room classes into files

Answer (score 4):

**Try this**
    get Column data from Cursor

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Category")
Cursor getAllCategory();
```

Answer (score 3):

To Export the Room Database data into `mydb.sqlite` file and store into External storage, follow the steps.

```
  fun exportDatabase(){
      val sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

      // Get the Room database storage path using SupportSQLiteOpenHelper 
      AppDatabase.getDatabase(applicationContext)!!.openHelper.writableDatabase.path

            if (sd.canWrite()) {
                val currentDBPath = AppDatabase.getDatabase(applicationContext)!!.openHelper.writableDatabase.path
                val backupDBPath = "mydb.sqlite"      //you can modify the file type you need to export
                val currentDB = File(currentDBPath)
                val backupDB = File(sd, backupDBPath)
                if (currentDB.exists()) {
                    try {
                        val src = FileInputStream(currentDB).channel
                        val dst = FileOutputStream(backupDB).channel
                        dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size())
                        src.close()
                        dst.close()
                    } catch (e: IOException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
            }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways i have tried to iterate over large Room database:

1- Get `Cursor` and iterate over that:

```
import android.database.Cursor
...
@Query("SELECT * FROM Category")
fun getAllCategory(): Cursor<Category>
...
val success = cursor.moveToFirst()
if (success) {
     while (!cursor.isAfterLast) {
         // Process items
         cursor.moveToNext()
     }
} else {
    // Empty
}
cursor.close()
```

2- Use `PagedList` to get pageSize amount of items at once and process. Then query another page and process:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Category")
fun getAllCategory(): DataSource.Factory<Int, Category>

// Here i will return Flowable. You can return LiveData with 'LivePagedListBuilder'
fun getCategories(pageSize: Int): Flowable<PagedList<Category>> {
        val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setPageSize(pageSize)
                .setPrefetchDistance(pageSize / 4)
                .setEnablePlaceholders(true)
                .setInitialLoadSizeHint(pageSize)
                .build()
        return RxPagedListBuilder(categoryDao.getAllCategory(), config)
                .buildFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
}
```

Now above `getCategories()` function will return `pagedList` inside `Flowable` or `LiveData`. Since we have set `setEnablePlaceholders(true)`, `pagedList.size` will show the whole size even if it is not in memory. So, if `pageSize` is 50 and all data size is 1000, `pagedList.size` will return 1000, but most of them will be null. To query next page and process:

```
// Callback is triggered when next page is loaded
pagedList.addWeakCallback(pagedList.snapshot(), object : PagedList.Callback() {
    override fun onChanged(position: Int, count: Int) {
        for (index in position until (position + count)) {
            if (index == (position + count - 1)) {
                if (index < (pagedList.size - 1)) 
                    pagedList.loadAround(index + 1)
                else{ 
                    // Last item is processed.
                }
            } else
                processCurrentValue(index, pagedList[index]!!)
        }
    }
    override fun onInserted(position: Int, count: Int) {
        // You better not change database while iterating over it 
    }    
    override fun onRemoved(position: Int, count: Int) {
        // You better not change database while iterating over it
    }
})

// Start to iterate and query next page when item is null.
for (index in 0 until pagedList.size) {
     if (pagedList[index] != null) {
            processCurrentValue(index, pagedList[index]!!)
     } else {
            // Query next page
            pagedList.loadAround(index)
            break
     }
}
```

---

**Conclusion**: In `PagedList` approach, you can get thousands of rows at once and process, while in `Cursor` approach you iterate row by row. I found `PagedList` unstable when pageSize > 3000. It does not return the page sometimes. So i used `Cursor`. It takes roughly about 5 minutes to iterate over (and process) 900k rows on both approaches on Android 8 phone.

Comment: Question is about exporting database and not about HOW TO USE PAGING LIBRARY!

Comment: It is about exorting db by iterating overvrows of tables. Because you might one to transform data while exporting. Exporting does not only mean dumping db and creating file from it with everything inside